# How to join multiple tables in entity framework using code first approach

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

```
select a.studentid, a.studentname, a.studentage, b.studentamount from students a join studentaccounts b
 ON a.studentid = b.studentid
```

How to write this in Controller class?
While creating corresponding view, do i have to mention both the classes?

```
@model IEnumerable<oneToOneRelationship.Student>
@model IEnumerable<oneToOneRelationship.Studentaccount>
```

help me out

Comment: It's not clear what you want to show and why you want to join. Also, you should probably use a navigation property instead of a join.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need.You can use `ViewModel` for that.

What is ViewModel ?

> In ASP.NET MVC, ViewModels allow you to shape multiple entities from
>   one or more data models or sources into a single object, optimized for
>   consumption and rendering by the view

[image]

Please see the [**full Article here**](http://rachelappel.com/use-viewmodels-to-manage-data-amp-organize-code-in-asp-net-mvc-applications/).